# How to combine data of rows in Excel

Tags: excel-2007

Please see my image

[image]

I have cells: A1 -> A8, Do you know what is the function that I can use to create a result as B11 (I want to use cell ranges, don't need list all specified cells)

Thanks and regards,
Tai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it can be done in a formula out of the box without the MoreFunc plugin.

This works (although it specifies each cell which is not what you want):

```
=CONCATENATE(A1 & ",",A2 & ",",A3 & ",",A4 & ",",A5 & ",",A6 & ",", A7)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had an answer from the link: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/511-merge-rows-keep-data.html